# DevExpress NavBarItem won't data bind properly in ContentTemplate that uses a WPF TreeView

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview, devexpress

I'm trying to organize my NavBarItem elements in each NavBarGroup into a tree view, using the following code:

```
<dxn:NavBarControl DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Bars}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
  <dxn:NavBarControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="dxn:NavBarGroup">
      <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding DisplayText}"/>
      <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding MenuItems}"/>
      <Setter Property="DisplaySource" Value="Content"/>
      <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TreeView x:Name="MenuView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
              <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildItems}"  >
                  <ContentControl>
                    <dxn:NavBarItem 
                      DataContext="{Binding}" 
                      Content="{Binding ItemText}" PreviewMouseUp="MenuItemOnPreviewMouseUp" Initialized="FrameworkContentElement_OnInitialized" />
                  </ContentControl>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
              </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
          </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </dxn:NavBarControl.Resources>
  <dxn:NavBarControl.View>
    <dxn:ExplorerBarView/>
  </dxn:NavBarControl.View>
</dxn:NavBarControl>
```

The groups are binding correctly, and I am only populating one group, "Personnel" for debugging reasons, with the mini-hierarchy:

```
"Personnel"
--"Employees"
----"Contractors"
------"Time-sheets"
```

I get the correct structure in the treeview, but each item only has the text that would result from calling `NavBarItem.ToString()`. When I handle the `NavBarItem.Initialized` even, the `sender` argument, being a `NavBarItem` actually has the correct value in its `Content` property, so the binding isn't all broken, but I don't know what is, and am seeking help here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is necessary to notice that NavBarGroup and NavBarItem are non-visual elements. Thus if you use them as the ContentPresenter content only simple strings will be shown (just like you see in your case).

The second thing is that multi-level hierarchy is not supported in NavBar (only group level and item level).

So if you need to show more than two levels you can use TreeView as you used in your sample but put TreeViewItems to the content template instead of putting NavBarItems; If you need only two levels you can use NavBarControl.ItemsSource and NavBarGroup.ItemsSource properties to populate layout.

Comment: Thanks @Alexis, I was using TreeViewItem, but I tried NavBarItem in order to get the same selection events and visual effects. I guess his laziness will have to code those himself :-)